# Extjs loading progress bar

Tags: javascript, extjs, pace.js

I'm using pace.js to have a bar loader before app.js load, but it isn't really nice. In case of fast or not fast connection the bar arrives to 99% and stop here for some time.

I've seen that i can set a gif like mask, but is it possible to have a progress bar instead of a gif?

Others solutions instead of pace.js are accepted.

Comment: I think a progress bar cannot really be used because you cannot find out how much of app.js has already been downloaded.

Comment: Have a look at the Sencha Touch loading indicator. You may use something similar for ExtJS

Comment: I'm trying to use a speed test to define more or less the time of the download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem using a connection speed detector before load my app js, and calculating how much time it gives to be load.

Before starting pace i detect the speed and set pace params dinamically.

Sometimes not really perfect but it is pretty good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those still having issues with this, use:

```
paceOptions = {
      elements: {
        selectors: ['.x-body']
      }
}
```

Works like a charm. Tested using extjs versions 4.2 and 6 and pace.js 1.0.0